# Spring.NET ObjectDefinitionStoreException using assembly to store configuration files

Tags: c#, spring.net

I am learning Spring.Net, I created a class MyApplication and a library class MyLib with all the spring configuration files that MyApplication needs.

I retrieve the metadata using:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("assembly...");
```

I have three different xml files, one (springconfiguration.xml) imports the two other. At the beginning of my tries, my spring configuration files were at the root level of MyLib. Everything worked fine.

```
----- MyLib
-- Properties
-- References
-- commonspring.xml
-- buttonspring.xml
-- springconfiguration.xml
```

Then I created some folders in MyLib to store my xml files and it fails if I use subfolders:

the following works:

```
----- MyLib
--Properties
--References
--Common
    --commonspring.xml
--Gui   
    --buttonspring.xml
--Configuration
    --springconfiguration.xml
```

my springconfiguration.xml file is then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
<import resource="Common/commonspring.xml"/>
<import resource="Gui/buttonspring.xml"/>
</objects>
```

and I retrieve the context with:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("assembly://MyLib/MyLib/Configuration.springconfiguration.xml");
```

but if I use subfolders then it fails:

```
----- MyLib
--Properties
--References
--Common
    --commonspring.xml
--Gui
    --SpecialButton
        --buttonspring.xml
--Configuration
    --springconfiguration.xml
```

my springconfiguration.xml file is then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
<import resource="Common/commonspring.xml"/>
<import resource="Gui/SpecialButton/buttonspring.xml"/>
</objects>
```

and I retrieve the context with:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("assembly://MyLib/MyLib/Configuration.springconfiguration.xml");
```

The error is:

```
{"Error registering object defined in 'assembly [MyLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [MyLib.Configuration.springconfiguration.xml] at line 5' : Invalid relative resource location 'Gui/SpecialButton/buttonspring.xml' to import object definitions from.\r\n<import resource=\"Gui/SpecialButton/buttonspring.xml\" xmlns=\"http://www.springframework.net\" />"}
```

I tried several syntaxes, I looked in the documentation and did not find any solution. Has someone an idee of where is the problem?

**Update**
ok I found by myself: the correct syntaxe is:

```
<import resource="Gui.SpecialButton.buttonspring.xml"/>
```

then no errors are raised anymore and everything work fine.

Comment: That's because the project folder is used as a namespace provider by VS. Btw you can answer your own question and accept it; that's useful for others, because they'll see your question is answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let everybody know here is the solution I found: in springconfiguration.xml instead of refering to the spring configuration file nested in folders as:

```
<import resource="Gui/SpecialButton/buttonspring.xml"/>
```

One has to write:

```
<import resource="Gui.SpecialButton.buttonspring.xml"/>
```

@marijn: thank you for your explanation, understanding a solution is better than just finding it ;)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know this was solved. You can accept you own answer too, but you might have to wait some time before you can.